# Hibernate xml enum mappnig

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, enum

Есть enum в java, есть enum(это не table, это object type) в pgDB.
Как выглядит mapping в hibernate данной конструкции?

Или такого варианта нет? Только org.hibernate.type.EnumType с переводом в число или строку?

Answer (score 1):

SQL

```
CREATE TYPE modern_gender AS ENUM ('MALE', 'FEMALE', 'ATTACKHELICOPTER');
```

Java

```
public class PostgreSQLEnumType extends org.hibernate.type.EnumType {
    public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index,
      SharedSessionContractImplementor session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        if (value == null) {
            st.setNull(index, Types.OTHER);
        }
        else {
            st.setObject(index, value.toString(), Types.OTHER);
        }
    }
}

public enum ModernGender {
    MALE,
    FEMALE,
    ATTACKHELICOPTER;
}

@Entity
@TypeDef(name = "pgsql_enum", typeClass = PostgreSQLEnumType.class)
public class Person {
    @Column(columnDefinition = "modern_gender")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Type(type = "pgsql_enum")
    private ModernGender gender;
}
```

XML-конфигурацией уже очень давно не пользовался, скорее всего должно быть что-то вроде этого:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.example.Person">
        <property name="gender">
            <type name="com.example.PostgreSQLEnumType">
                <param name="enumClass">com.example.ModernGender</param>
                <param name="useNamed">true</param>
            </type>
            <column name="gender" sql-type="modern_gender"/>
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Спасибо, вариант с аннотациями мне более менее понятен. Как это отразить в xml описании конфига.

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: К сожалению этот вариант приводит к строке, а если параметр useNamed = false то к integer

Comment: Забыл добавить важный элемент. Проверьте.